# Android: Duplicate class XX found in modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aar

Good morning friends, I need help.

This project needs to use these two libraries. And when compiling they are having a conflict because there are certain classes.

In fact, I already separated them as "independent" modules and I keep getting the error.

I call the two libraries in the `build.gradle (:app)` like this:

```
    implementation project(path: ':smartill')
    implementation project(path: ':smartill-mini-plus')
```

also, add in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Any ideas to separate them?

[image]

[image]

Error text:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkPaStagingDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.dm.commonlib.ThreadPoolManager found in 
modules jetified-smart_minilib_v1.0.9-runtime.jar 
(smart_minilib_v1.0.9.aar) and jetified-tilllib-runtime.jar (tilllib.aar)
Duplicate class com.dm.commonlib.Utils found in modules jetified-smart_minilib_v1.0.9- 
runtime.jar (smart_minilib_v1.0.9.aar) and jetified-tilllib-runtime.jar (tilllib.aar)
```